# How to reveal all the explicit bazel targets packed into a macro

Tags: bazel

I'm diagnosing some codegen and it's backed by some bazel macro backed by a custom bazel rule.

```py
#projX/BUILD
macro_foo(
    name = "foo_data"
    ...
)

py_binary(
    name = "client_foo_data",
    deps = [":foo_data"]
    ...
)
```

If I build the raw macro target the code gen doesn't actually execute. If I build a target that's a reverse dependency on `foo_data` the codegen does execute.

```sh
bazel build //projX:foo_data # doesn't trigger codegen
bazel build //projY:client_foo_data # does codegen
```

How can I ferret out all the distinct target names packed under the hood for a given target? I suspect I need to build one of those specific variants to tickle the codegen; some kind of bazel query or something that unpacks the targets under a macro should do the trick.

---

### VScode Codelens Build/Test Links

As a directly applicable aside, in VSCode it used to decorate my macros and other things that expanded to multiple bazel targets and I could click on the links to initiate a build or a test (some upgrade lost this capability for me, I used to lean on it to find these target variants). This is what they called their codelens feature

> **CodeLens** links in BUILD files to directly launch a build or test by simply clicking on the targets

https://github.com/bazelbuild/vscode-bazel#features

You can get a glimpse of it here for the annotation "Another Shortcut"
[image: annotated screenshot of the vscode bazel plugin]
https://kig.re/2020/03/21/building-intellij-bazel-plugin.html

Understanding the mechanism the bazel plugin uses for how it discovers all the specific target variants that unfold from a given target should point in the right direction. If there's some concept/vocabulary/terminology surrounding this detail knowing that would help understand what's going on too.

Comment: I should note for any others that land here from the codlens part, it's actually a configuration in your bazel extension settings. Mine was unchecked at some point so that feature had been unknowingly disabled for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the query the vscode plugin was using, they're basically using a kind rule query

```
  const queryResult = await new BazelQuery(
    bazelExecutable,
    workspace,
    `kind(rule, ${pkg}:all)`,
    [],
  ).queryTargets();
```

https://github.com/bazelbuild/vscode-bazel/blob/12c20773c5bbbdbbd30cc393c414622059c05537/src/bazel/bazel_utils.ts#L45-L50

To get what I was going for I ran the following command...

```sh
bazel query 'kind(rule, //projX:all)' | grep foo_data
```

that exposed all the "suffixed" variants we employ in the rules, eg

```
//projX:foo_data_variant1
//projX:foo_data_variant2
//projX:foo_data_variant3
...
//projX:foo_data
```

that `all` trick was the key, if I ran the command with just the target name I only get that one back :-(

```
bazel query 'kind(rule, //projX:foo_data)'
//projX:foo_data
```

**Sidenote**

The thing that was deceiving in the use case for the project I was on was that the "basename" passed into the macro is actually used as a target within the macro. So the fallacy I suffered from was to think that because a macro has a name argument that that macro is itself a target, it is not, and it could be very well that the name given to the macro is passed on to some actual bazel rule target which should not be confused with the macro even if they share a common name. One is the name that becomes part of the actual label, the other is just an argument to a macro/function.

Answer (score 2):

`bazel query --output=build //projX:all` will print out all the targets in that package after macro and glob expansion. It has comments with the macro expansion stack traces for each target, including filenames and line numbers for the macro definitions.

`//projX:all` is form of [wildcard](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#specifying-targets-to-build) which specifies all the targets in that [package](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#packages). Macros can only generate targets in a single package, so that will always include all targets generated from that macro invocation.